# Double pointer to traverse and find 5 max elem in 2D array. C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, double-pointer

So am trying to do a question that aims to find 5 max elements in int 2D array.
I had no issues with dynamically allocating the array and inputting the elements into it.

```
printf("Your 2-d order of choice?\n");
    scanf ("%d %d", &i ,&j);
    int array[i][j];
    //Taking 2d array input
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < j; d++) 
        {
            scanf("%d", &array[c][d]);
        }
    }
```

However, to find the 5 max elements and store them in an array it asks for a function with prototype.

```
int * max5(int **, int ,int)
```

I don’t know how to use double pointer to traverse the 2D array, even though I read a few other posts regarding `int**`, and what will `int*` (return type) exactly be and how to incorporate it.

Comment: Who gave you that prototype for the function?

Comment: double pointer points to the address of single pointer

Answer (score 1):

There are the many ways to pass array as pointers

As per you said that if you take array like `int array[10][10];`.

Using single pointer you can do like

```
int *arr = max5 ((int *)array, 10, 10);
```

And traverse array as

```
int * max5 (int *arr, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));

    //.........
}
```

OR using double pointer you can also do like

```
 int *arr =  max5 ((int **)array, 10, 10);
```

And traverse like

```
int * max5 (int **arr, int m, int n)// Same as int * max5 (int *arr[], int m, int n)
{

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));

    //.........
}
```

Now other way also possible it just for your information

From C99, C language supports variable sized arrays to be passed simply by specifying the variable dimensions.

```
int *arr =  max5 (array, 10, 10);
```

And traverse like

```
int * max5 (int arr[][10],int m,int n) //Same as int * max5 ( int (*arr)[10], int m,int n))
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);

     //.........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the given prototype, you have to declare `array` as `int **` and dynamically allocate memory to it.

```
int **array = malloc(i*sizeof(int*)); 
for(int row = 0; row < i; row++)
    array[row] = malloc(j*sizeof(int));
```

Now you can call your `max5` function as

```
int *a = max5(array, i, j);
```

Then dynamically allocate an array inside `max5` and return it from `max5`.

Comment: You did the 1st part of the answer (that I didn't write in my own). However there is a small glitch: the *col* for-loop is not necessary (plus some leakage) and could be simply removed. Moreover `array[i]` should be `array[row]`.

Comment: @ring0; Hmmm. That was not a mistake but was a blunder!

Answer (score 0):

This is the *max5* function.

It gets 5 elements in *res* (allocated by malloc), then for the remaining elements of *a*, it finds the smallest elements of *res* and compare it with that *a* element - if the *res* element is maller than the *a* element, that *res* element is replaced with the *a* one.

Note that I wouldn't usually use a magic number (5) in the function, but since it's called *max5* ..

```
#include <limits.h>

int *max5(int **a, int rows, int cols) {
    int *res = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    int i,j,k,n=0; // n, number of elements in res

    for (i=0 ; i<rows ; i++) {
       for (j=0 ; j<cols ; j++) {
          if (n < 5) res[n++] = a[i][j];
          else {
             // find lowest res element
             int lowest=0;
             for(k=1 ; k<5 ; k++) { // start from 1!
                if (res[k] < res[lowest]) {
                    lowest = k;
                }
             }
             // if lowest res is < a[i][j], replace it
             if (res[lowest] < a[i][j]) res[lowest] = a[i][j];
          }
       }
    }
    return res;
}
```

For the sake of demo, this is not optimized (looking for the *min* all the time). One way would be to sort the *res* array after 5 elements have been inserted, and after one of its element is replaced (which should statistically happen less and less over the iterations). Another way would be to build a tree when the elements are input initially.

As mentioned by @haccks, *array* is to be declared as a `int **`, then *i* rows must be `int *` allocated (ie, *i* pointers to *int*), then each of the row is to be allocated the size of *j* *int*.